# iOS - WKWebView - Caching the previous state of the application during subsequent app launches

Tags: ios, swift, caching, browser, wkwebview

We have an iOS application which uses WkWebView to load a web application on Apple iPod's. It supports auto-login feature without having user to manually enter the credentials. We use a POST html form submission logic with credentials to simulate the auto-login.

The web application has a timeout for 15 mins and after that, uses will be logged out and redirected to the login screen and a message called "Time out" will be displayed on the login screen.

The problem we are seeing is, whenever user launches the app freshly (which is not running at that moment either in background/foreground), the expectation is the Form submission will be loaded as HTML on the webview and either user will login (if credentials are correct) (or) user will be redirected to login screen (with Invalid credentials message).

webview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: myURL)

But in this case, user is redirected to login screen with a message "Time Out" (Which is the previous state of the app). User tried to kill the app (double tap home button and swipe up) and re-launch app and after 2-3 attempts, he is successfully getting authenticated and going to home screen. For all the first 2-3 attempts, he is seeing "Time Out" message which is not expected.

Is WKWebView caching the page for some reason (or) iOS app is doing something wrong? Any suggestions on how to debug this will be greatly appreciated.

Note: Our business doesn't want to clear the cache as its taking ~20secs to load without cache every-time. Hence we cache the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just test clearing all the `WebView` data and see if it helps. Try the code below in `deinit{}` of the `ViewController` or where you clean up after the app if being closed.

Code below will delete all the data associated with the web session that happened.

```
for cookie in HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies ?? [] {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(
            ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(),
            modifiedSince: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0),
            completionHandler:{})
```

Comment: Hi Mishka, thanks for your answer. This is something we want to try out and test to understand if thats the root cause or not. But our business is not happy with clearing the cache as a permanent solution since its taking lot of time during each app launch.